# How to sum column values from Parse with Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform, sum

I have a query set up in Swift, that retrieves some values from a particular column. I'm trying to return the amount of objects that are in accordance with the query, and then sum up the rating numbers of the customer's rating column, to later divide them with the amount of orders, in order to get an average. I found on StackOverflow, that I could do this by storing the different rating values in an array, but for some reason, only one value is stored in the array, so I keep getting an error. Here's the code:

```
var ordersArray: [Int]!

let query = PFQuery(className: "Orders")
query.whereKey("customer", equalTo: customerLet)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({(objects, error) -> Void in
     if objects!.count == 0{
        self.ratingLabel.text = ("5.0")
     }else{
        if let objects = objects{
           for object in objects{
             let ordersAmount = objects!.count            
             self.ordersArray.append((Int(object.objectForKey("rating") as! String))!
             let totalOrders = self.ordersArray.reduce(0, combine: +)
             let ratingAverage = (totalOrders / ordersAmount)
                                }
                              }
                      }
            })
```

Comment: can you share full code for this method, you need to calculate ratingAverage outside the loop.

Comment: @Shabirjan that's essentially the full code, I just skipped the first block of the if statement because it is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: actually the thing is there are no closing brackets so thats why i asked you to share full code for this method.

Comment: add breakpoint on self.ordersArray.append and see whether you the objects are being added into the array or not

Comment: Thank you. It says `objects = 3 values` but only one of them is retrieved from "rating". The values for "rating" are 4, 4 and 5, but I only get one value returned, and it's a 4.

Comment: now for that can you please share full code of for loop of objects?

Comment: @Shabirjan that's the one in the question, there's nothing after that except for closing brackets, which I'm adding.

Comment: check my answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also the issue is that your array is not being initialized correctly. It should be like that :

```
var ordersArray: [Int] = []()
```

Try this.

```
for object in objects{           
    self.ordersArray.append((Int(object.objectForKey("rating") as! String))!   
}


let ordersAmount = objects!.count 
let totalOrders = self.ordersArray.reduce(0, combine: +)
let ratingAverage = (totalOrders / ordersAmount)
```

Comment: Thanks. It still stops working at self.ordersArray.append... "rating" still only returns its value from one row instead of three although it says `objects = 3 values`. In addition to that, it says the array is nil.

Comment: which array is nil? and try to add breakpoint on totalOrders, see what is the value of ordersAmount, totalOrders and self.ordersArray.

Comment: if possible we can do small teamviewer session to find out bug

Comment: i am available now

Comment: Perfect, I use a software called zoom.us because team viewer crashes on computer. Do you have it?

Comment: Ok i just created account.

Comment: Alright, we can give team viewer a try. Are you sending an invite?